# Android Firebase -Cards not displaying in RecyclerView and NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am trying to build an app where users can post something with image and description which is included individually in `CardView` in `RecyclerView`. So I have have got three problems

1.When `id(userId)` is used as child and then I post the data it gets replaced with old data instead of adding new data (if the posts has multiple children with same ID then my cards should display but the ID is getting replaced every time)

2. Cards aren't showing when a post is added.(When there are posts in
   Firebase database)
3. If by default there are no posts in Firebase database
   `NullPointerException` to the method `getDesc()` is generated even
   though I have put null checks.

Earlier for storing posts the child I used was `id(userId)`, but the posts got replaced instead of adding a new one so I used a random String generator and tried to fetch information from it instead.

HomeFragment.java

```java
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView rv;
    private TextView username,date,desc;
    private CircleImageView postImage;
    private ImageView postBigImage;
    private CardView postCard;
    private List<PostActivity> postItems;
    private DatabaseReference dr;
    private StorageReference sr;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    //FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostActivity, userViewHolder> fra;


    private PostAdapter pa;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        sr = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String id = user.getUid();

        AddPost ap = new AddPost();

        dr = 
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts")
      .child(ap.getUni());

        postItems = new ArrayList<>();
        pa = new PostAdapter(postItems);

        rv =view.findViewById(R.id.rvPostItems);

        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        rv.setAdapter(pa);



        dr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    //postItems.add(ds.getValue(PostActivity.class));

                    PostActivity pa =dataSnapshot.getValue(PostActivity.class);
                    postItems.add(pa);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

PostAdapter.java

```java
package com.pappu5.navigation;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<PostActivity> postItems;

    public PostAdapter(List<PostActivity> postItems) {
        this.postItems = postItems;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_items,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String descTe = postItems.get(position).getDesc();
        if(descTe!=null) {

            holder.setDesc(descTe);
        }else{
            String def = "This is NULL";
            holder.setDesc(def);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {


        return postItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView desc;
        private View mView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDesc(String descText){
            desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.postDesc);

                desc.setText(descText);

        }
    }

}
```

AddPost.java

```java
package com.pappu5.navigation;

public class AddPost extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ImageView postImage;
    private Button postButton;
    private EditText postDesc;
    private static final int gallery_no = 1;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private StorageReference sr;
    private DatabaseReference dr;
    private Uri postImageUri = null;
    private Bitmap compressor;
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());



    protected String getSaltString() {
        String SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (salt.length() < 18) { // length of the random string.
            int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length());
            salt.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
        }
        String saltStr = salt.toString();
        return saltStr;

    }

    String uni = getSaltString();

    public String getUni(){
        return this.uni;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_post);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.postBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add New Post !");

        postImage = findViewById(R.id.postImage);
        postDesc = findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
        postButton = findViewById(R.id.post);

        sr = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String id = user.getUid();


        dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(uni);
        dr.keepSynced(true);


        postImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent();
                gallery.setType("image/*");
                gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery,"Select Image"),gallery_no);
            }
        });

        postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String desc = postDesc.getText().toString();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc) && postImageUri!=null ){
                    pd = new ProgressDialog(AddPost.this);
                    pd.setTitle("Uploading..");
                    pd.setMessage("Please Wait ..");
                    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    pd.show();

                    final String id = user.getUid();


                    File thumb = new File(postImageUri.getPath());
                    try {
                        compressor = new Compressor(AddPost.this)
                                .setMaxWidth(200)
                                .setMaxHeight(200)
                                .setQuality(75)
                                .compressToBitmap(thumb);




                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    compressor.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

                    final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();



                    final StorageReference path = sr.child("Post_Images").child(id + ".jpg");

                    final StorageReference thumb_nail = sr.child("Post_Images").child("Thumb_Nails").child(id+".jpg");

                    path.putFile(postImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                path.putFile(postImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        path.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                final String down_url = uri.toString();

                                                UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_nail.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                                                uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                                                        thumb_nail.putFile(postImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                                thumb_nail.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {


                                                                        final String thumb_down_url = uri.toString();

                                                                        Map <String,Object> update_map = new HashMap<>();
                                                                        update_map.put("image", down_url);
                                                                        update_map.put("thumb_image", thumb_down_url);
                                                                        update_map.put("desc",desc);

                                                                        update_map.put("timestamp", date);

                                                                        dr.updateChildren(update_map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                            @Override
                                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                                    Toast.makeText(AddPost.this, "Uploaded !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddPost.this,MainActivity.class);
                                                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                                                    finish();

                                                                                    pd.dismiss();
                                                                                } else {
                                                                                    Toast.makeText(AddPost.this, "Error in uploading thumbnail!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                                    pd.dismiss();
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        });



                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                });

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(AddPost.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }
            }
        });

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == gallery_no && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(imageUri).setAspectRatio(1, 1).setMinCropWindowSize(500, 500)
                    .start(AddPost.this);
        }


        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                postImageUri = result.getUri();
                postImage.setImageURI(postImageUri);



            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

post_items.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/postCard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.56"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/postImage"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/postImage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="Datee"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/postImage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/postUsername" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/postBigImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/postImage"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[3]" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postDesc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/postBigImage" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To fix NullPointerException check null value of postItems.get(position) instead of postItems.get(position).getDesc() i.e.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(postItems.get(position) != null) {
        String descTe = postItems.get(position).getDesc();

        holder.setDesc(descTe);
    } else {
        String def = "This is NULL";
        holder.setDesc(def);
    }
}
```

Also, you are initializing PostAdapter with blank List of postItems, i.e.

```
postItems = new ArrayList<>();
pa = new PostAdapter(postItems);
```

and Items are added later inSide onDataChange() method of the ValueEventListener. you must update your PostAdapter for the new updated List postItems and notify the adapter. like this.

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                //postItems.add(ds.getValue(PostActivity.class));

                PostActivity pa =dataSnapshot.getValue(PostActivity.class);
                postItems.add(pa);

            }
            pa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

And for Cards not being displayed can you share the code of post_items.xml file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer bro ,yes i have put the xml file above now

Comment: what i need to update exactly?can you elaborate please? Also before when i used child as id the card used to display but data with Id was being replaced instead of adding so i used random string and now even that one card has gone

Comment: just add pa.notifyDataSetChanged(); once all the items are added to postItems.

Comment: Oh yes i added that previously but now its saying  Cannot resolve method "notifyDataSetChanged();" so i removed that statement

Comment: I have updated the code. check OnDataChange() method

Comment: Yes bro i did exactly what you said but the cards are still not displaying

Comment: make sure postItems List have items added. you can check it using postItems.size(). Also, check if onCancelled() method isn't getting called due to some database error.

Comment: How do i check that? i mean Log requires string parameters and the size is int so is there any alternative to check the size?

Comment: Bro i checked with System.out.println and the size is 0 lol i mean whats going on?

Comment: Though this type of questions are not accepted, still you can use Log.d("Log", "postItesm.size(): " + postItems.size()); Also put a log on onCanceled() to check it it is called.

Comment: it means onCanceled() is being called check the cause.

Comment: But why is it called ?I mean whats the exact issue although everything looks fine ah i am scratching my head

Comment: Now the problem is in the way you are adding the post in DB. you have to check it carefully again.

Comment: Bro i have added an image link in the end of the post you can check my firebase

Comment: the issue is in the way you are adding a post into the firebase, at first look, I found you have added the listeners to path.putFile() in nested order, which shouldn't be you can refer https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-upload-to-firebase-in-android-application--cms-29934 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPOhnTnLcSY for detail

Comment: Bro previously in my other segment of app i used the same approach to display the user chats in the form of cards and it displayed everything correctly i.e image,text etc but i dont understand where am i going wrong ,can you please check the database reference lines? am i pointing to the right child path?

Comment: Here you go bro http://prntscr.com/o49q5t
its like Post_Images --> Main Image and Folder for Thumbnails--->ThumbImage

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted an answer on behalf of the question author).*

I solved every problem by removing whole `PostAdapter` class and then implementing `FireebaseRecyclerAdapter` in the `HomeFragment` itself ! My cards are displaying like charm now ! Thanks to everyone who replied to me here and helped me.